# How to know when the ripples have died down within the GLCameraRipple example?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I'm using the [GLCameraRipple example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html)  to have ripples over a static image, which I load with glTexImage2D.

I use my own shaders since those in the example are for getting images from video feed.

It responds to touches and generates ripples on the touch location.

It works ok, but I need it to pause drawing, for battery preservation reasons, when the ripple animation has finished. In this example from Apple, I don't see anywhere how I can check this state. GLKView or GLKViewController don't have any delegate method for this.

It uses a -runSimulation method that is called in every -update of my GLKViewController, which does all the magic, but I still don't see where I can check if the ripples have finished animating, or even compare the initial state with the state where ripples are running all over.

I am currently counting myself how much time the ripple animation takes to finish at most, until what we see is a static image again and I've set it to pause after this amount of seconds and unpause it again when a touch event occurs, but it doesn't feel right at all.
(The animation duration is different on larger screens (e.g. on iPad) and may vary depending on the pool size, mesh factor, touch radius etc.)

I was hoping there would be a way to check if the view's contents are different than the initial state (when I have just loaded the image) and know the ripple animation is done playing?

Comment: I don't know anything about this code sample, but one thing I am sure is that OpenGL doesn't animate anything : it only draws what ObjectiveC asks him to draw. So the counter of whatever must be inside runSimulation(), not inside OpenGL.

Comment: a cursory glance at the source shows that the ripple effect seems to be done by varying `s_tc` and `t_tc` using `s_offset` and `t_offset`, respectively. maybe testing if these offsets are close to zero (never use equality tests on floats) would do the trick?

Comment: I just checked this and s_tc is always 1 and t_tc is always 0.27 . only s_offset and t_offset vary, but they constantly change from some values of -5.9747857449110597e-05 to + 4.1495609366393182e-06 taking zero-close values randomly (?) . They never stop to or close to any particular value

Comment: This isn't really about OpenGL ES, but about the specific calculations performed in the GLCameraRipple example. OpenGL ES is only involved for rendering each frame, which happens every fraction of a second. What you want is to find when GLCameraRipple's ripple displacements have died down to an acceptable level. You need to observe the elements of the `rippleTexCoords` array within `-runSimulation` to find when the ripples have calmed below a certain threshold.

Comment: @BradLarson , that's it! I had checked rippleTexCoords but I was looking for some value to be equal with the same index before the ripples started. Values do calm down eventually to a level that tells me the effect is finished. Please make it an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I'm converting my comment to an answer so that the question can be closed out.

The GLCameraRipple example calculates the displacement for the texture coordinates in the image using an internal array called `rippleTexCoords`. This array is updated in the `-runSimulation` method on each frame, which is what causes the ripples to propagate.

If you observe the values of this array as they change, you can determine the point at which the ripples die down below a certain threshold. You can then use this as the time to pause the ongoing simulation.